# .htaccess opens .css instead of .php

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, file

I used this code in my .htaccess for the entire time:

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /404error.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It worked fine and I could use the filenames in the url without the extension. But out of nowhere the code stopped working and the same url (/index) brought me to, instead of the /index.php to the /index.css. (This effects only me local apache - The online server works still fine)
Why did it stopped working and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance - Jojo

Comment: have you checked your server log? I know sometimes if you dont use any other directives with indexes in apache  you can get strange behavior.

Comment: nothing there :( But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this: [Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html)

In my .htaccess I disabled MultiViews like this

```
Options -MultiViews
```

and it worked fine!

-- Problem solved :)